# How to change the order of facet labels in ggplot (custom facet wrap labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted a facet plot using `ggplot`  and here is the plot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qXF1.png]

The problem I have is, The facets(labels) are sorted alphabetically (Ex: E1, E10, E11,E13, E2, E3, I1, I10, I2) but I need them to be a custom order like E1, I1, E2, I2, E3, E10, I10, E11, E13.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Rearrange the order of the underlying factor. You can use `relevel()` or `reorder()` or make a custom order and use `factor()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing the order of facets in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262497/fixing-the-order-of-facets-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Don't rely on the default ordering of levels imposed by `factor()` or internally by `ggplot` if the grouping variable you supply is **not** a factor. Set the levels explicitly yourself.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), 
                  Group = gl(5, 20, labels = LETTERS[1:5]))
head(dat)
with(dat, levels(Group))
```

What if I want them in this arbitrary order?

```
set.seed(1)
with(dat, sample(levels(Group)))
```

To do this, set the levels the way you want them.

```
set.seed(1) # reset the seed so I get the random order form above
dat <- within(dat, Group <- factor(Group, levels = sample(levels(Group))))
with(dat, levels(Group))
```

Now we can use this to have the panels drawn in the order *we* want:

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) + geom_bar()
p + facet_wrap( ~ Group)
```

Which produces:

[image: facets wrapped]

Comment: Same as above but if the data itself is already in the custom order you want the `Group`  variable to be in and you don't want to manually create a vector in that order: `dat <- within(dat, Group <- factor(Group, levels = unique(levels(Group))))` since `unique` preserves the order

Comment: Good answer, solved my problem but felt I should add a comment in case any others come across the issue I was having: If you have two data sources being called at different times (e.g. in the initial ggplot() and a different data in geom_line()), then both data sources must have the faceting variable factored and ordered in the same way for them to plot in the desired order.

Answer (score 3):

Just being working on a similar problem. I have levels which look like this by default:

```
 [1] "A1"  "A10" "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9" 
[11] "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9"
```

Note that the second level is out of place due to alphabetical order.

This is what I am doing to fix the order:

```
reorder(factor(fct),
        fct %>%
          str_replace("([[:alpha:]]+)", "\\1|") %>%
          str_split("\\|") %>%
          sapply(function(d) sprintf("%s%02d", d[1], as.integer(d[2]))),
        function(x) x[1])
```

It replaces levels like "A1" with "A01" then reorders according to these. I'm sure that you could do this a lot more efficiently, but it does the job.

It could be adapted to address the original problem.