# Add group levels to data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

In 
[How to change the order of facet labels in ggplot (custom facet wrap labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490638/how-to-change-the-order-of-facet-labels-in-ggplot-custom-facet-wrap-labels) it is described how to add group levels for later use in a sorted facet grid.

How can I generate group levels to `mtcars` that will turn the number of cylinders in the reversed order?

Comment: What is wrong with the answer provided in the question to which you linked?

Comment: `Group = gl(5, 20, labels = LETTERS[1:5])` assumes that I have 5*20 items, but how will I have to sort it with 30+50+20 items for example?

Comment: something like `within(mtcars, Group = factor(cylinder, levels = rev(sort(unique(cylinder))))` should suffice.

Comment: `within(mtcars, Group <- factor(cyl, levels = rev(sort(unique(cyl)))))`. typo on my behalf, (now has been tested)

Comment: works on mtcars and with my data too. Could you make it an answer? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to sort the unique values, and then set the levels as the reverse.

for example.

```
mtcars <- within(mtcars, Group <- factor(cyl, levels = rev(sort(unique(cyl)))))


ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~Group)
```

Comment: that works. Now I can combine it with the results from the cited question.