# Fixing the order of facets in ggplot when using dplyr to transform data to long form

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-grid

I got help here yesterday to create a facet grid of multiple columns. This yielded a large grid containing 8*5 plots. The code creates a combination of plot for various Outcomes * Responses. For example (Outcome1 * Response1, Outcome1 * Response2, Outcome3 * Response1, Outcome2 * Response1 and so on).

I have pasted the code below.

```
plot1 <- ancestralmeansindex %>%
gather(var1, value1, bicepind:wcind) %>%
gather(var2, value2, mmois:mpfat) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = value1, y = value2)) + 
geom_point(color='blue') +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
facet_grid(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", switch = "both",
         labeller = as_labeller(c(mmois = "Water (gms)",
                                  mkcal = "Caloric Intake",
                                  mprot = "Protein (gms)",
                                  mcarb = "Carb (gms)",
                                  mtfat = "Total Fat (gms)",
                                  msfat = "Saturated Fat (gms)",
                                  mmfat = "Mono S.Fat (gms)",
                                  mpfat = "Poly US.Fat (gms)",
                                  bicepind = "Bicep",
                                  tricepind = "Tricep",
                                  subind = "Subscapular",
                                  supind = "Suprailiac",
                                  weightind = "Weight",
                                  wcind = "Waist Circum"))) +
  labs(title = "Regression Plot Matrix of Mean Dietary Values with    Index Change 1", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
theme_bw() +
theme(strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank())
ggsave("Regression Plot 1.pdf", width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm", plot1)
```

This gives a very neat grid of all the possible combinations mentioned in the code. However, the graph prints the plots in alphabetical order (as it is reflected in the labeller/data). I would like to change this order for both var2 and var1.

I read in the help that this problem can be solved by assigning factor levels and choosing a given order. For example, this solution [Fixing the order of facets in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262497/fixing-the-order-of-facets-in-ggplot)

How do I assign factor levels to variables that have been converted to long form by dplyr? Can this be done? Is there another solution?

Edit1 I tried the solution below, but I am running into an error. Reproducible example below.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  Outcome1 = sample(1:10),
  Outcome2 = sample(11:20),
  Outcome3 = sample(21:30),
  Response1 = sample(31:40),
  Response2 = sample(41:50),
  Response3 = sample(51:60)
)

dat %>%
  gather(var1, value1, Outcome1:Outcome3) %>%
  mutate(var1, recode("Outcome1" = "Bicep",
                      "Outcome2" = "Tricep",
                      "Outcome3" = "Subscapular")) %>%
  factor(var1, levels = c("Bicep",
                          "Tricep",
                          "Subscapular")) 
gather(var2, value2, Response1:Response3) %>% 
  mutate(var2, recode("Response1" = "Water (gms)", 
                      "Response2" = "Caloric Intake",
                      "Response3" = "Protein (gms)")) %>%
  factor(var2, levels = c("Water (cms)", 
                          "Caloric Intake",
                          "Protein (gms)")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value1, y = value2)) + 
  geom_point(color='blue') +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", switch = "both",
             labeller = as_labeller(c(mmois = "Water (gms)",
                                      mkcal = "Caloric Intake",
                                      mprot = "Protein (gms)",
                                      bicepind = "Bicep",
                                      tricepind = "Tricep",
                                      subind = "Subscapular"))) +
  labs(title = "Regression Plot", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())


Error in factor(., var1, levels = c("Bicep", "Tricep", "Subscapular",  : 
  object 'var1' not found

Error in gather(var2, value2, Response1:Response3) : 
  object 'var2' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It can be done. Use dplyr `mutate` to `recode` your var1 and var2 variables, then use `factor` to ensure the levels are in the right order. Then you won't need to use the labeler. Thanks to your reproducible example I was able to test my solution and fix the code!

```
 dat %>%
  gather(var1, value1, Outcome1:Outcome3) %>%
  mutate(var1 = recode(var1, "Outcome1" = "Bicep",
                      "Outcome2" = "Tricep",
                      "Outcome3" = "Subscapular")) %>%
  mutate(var1 = factor(var1, levels = c("Bicep",
                          "Tricep",
                          "Subscapular"))) %>% 
gather(var2, value2, Response1:Response3) %>% 
  mutate(var2 = recode(var2, "Response1" = "Water (gms)", 
                      "Response2" = "Caloric Intake",
                      "Response3" = "Protein (gms)"),
          var2 = factor(var2, levels = c("Water (gms)", 
                          "Caloric Intake",
                          "Protein (gms)"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value1, y = value2)) + 
  geom_point(color='blue') +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", switch = "both") +
  labs(title = "Regression Plot", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would I add this line of code? After gather?

Comment: Yup, you can use another `%>%` to add both lines, then carry on with your ggplot. Let me know if you can't get it to work (after reading the help files for recode, of course :P). It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example, too!

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this but get an error. Could you please have a look at the original post? I have added what you suggested. And the error I am getting. Many thanks.

Comment: This is the error Error in factor(., var1, levels = c("Bicep", "Tricep", "Subscapular",  : 
  object 'var1' not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: perfect try my edits. sorry my original answer was hastily written.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I have it in a correct order now.