# R: ggplot2 facets will not obey factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am using ggplot to make three plots using `facet_grid()`.  The default order of the plots & legend is alphabetical.  To adjust the order, I factored the relevant variable and confirmed that the intended levels were set.  However, the plots still appear in alphabetical order.  Factoring did adjust the sample-order in the legend and color assignments, but not the order of the plots.

I found many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262497/fixing-the-order-of-facets-in-ggplot) that add factors within plot creation, but I want to factor my data beforehand so that the plot code stays as simple as possible.

Can anyone explain why my factoring method isn't working for plot arrangement in facets?  Is there a simple way to add factor levels before plot creation that `facet_grid()` will obey?

```
library(tidyverse)

Sample_Table <- data.frame(
  Sample=c(1:9),
  Group=c("B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"))

data <- data.frame(
  Position=c(rep(1:5000,times=3)),
  Signal=c(rep(0,times=2000), rep(25,times=1000), rep(0,times=2000),
           rep(0,times=2000), rep(50,times=1000), rep(0,times=2000),
           rep(0,times=2000), rep(75,times=1000), rep(0,times=2000)),
  Group=c(rep("A", times=5000), rep("B", times=5000), rep("C", times=5000))
  )

data_factor <- data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels=c(paste0(unique(Sample_Table$Group)))))

colorscale <- c("#ffe119", "#f58231", "#9A6324")

Plot <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col=Group), linewidth=.4) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(colorscale)) +
  facet_grid(paste0(Group)~.) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#333333", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#333333", size=12)
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")

Plot_Factored <- ggplot(data_factor) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col=Group), linewidth=.4) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(colorscale)) +
  facet_grid(paste0(Group)~.) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#333333", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#333333", size=12)
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

Plot
[image: Plot]
Plot_Factored
[image: Plot_Factored]

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by your code. Can you expand a little on what you think `paste0()` is accomplishing in (1) setting the levels of your factor, and (2) specifying variables for faceting? Other than that, `unique()` is just repeating the levels B, A & C in the order they appear in `Sample_Table`, so ggplot is faithfully putting things in that order.

Comment: (As I suspected, removing `paste0()` from the `facet_grid()` call put the facets in the correct order as well as in the legend.)

Comment: Thank you.  I think `paste0()` within `facet_grid()` was something that had a function in a prior plot, and I didn't realize it wasn't needed in this iteration.