# How to use ggplot2 to plot from a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 x <- c(1:50)
 my=c(1:50)
 my.data <- data.frame(te=my, x=x)
 my.data3 <- my.data2 <- my.data1 <- my.data
 my.data=list(my.data1, my.data2, my.data3)
```

So I want to plot plot(te,x) for the three elements in the list using ggplot and facet_wrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the data.frames into one data.frame:

```
myDF <- Map(\(DF, g) {
  DF$g <- g
  DF}, my.data, seq_along(my.data))
myDF <- do.call(rbind, myDF)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(myDF, aes(te, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ g)
```

Comment: Yes, just replace the last argument of Map.

Comment: Replace `seq_along(my.data)` with the vector from your comment.

Comment: thanks, i put (Def, tog,hel), in the order i want and corresponds to the plots. but they are ordered in the plot  alpapitecally. can we solve this please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262497/1412059